# Instagram deprecation of Login

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Just need to know if login falls under the basic feature of the api which instagram has decided to deprecate on 2020, or it will be deprecated well before that.Also need to know if user endpoint always fall under basic?.Is there any instagram login api in the facebook graph api endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar type of this question (you can read it here [Importing user photos vs. Instagram platform API depreciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534621/importing-user-photos-vs-instagram-platform-api-depreciation/52694682#52694682)).

> or it will be deprecated well before that?

The answer is, **nobody knows**. Instagram own all of it's own data and have rights to deprecate the API anytime they wanted to.

> Also need to know if user endpoint always fall under basic?

I think so, yes. This is because one of the reason Instagram API is now restricted to your own user is some developers misused API endpoints.

> Is there any instagram login api in the facebook graph api endpoint?

Yes, there is. But you will need to link your facebook account, enable business profile in your Instagram. Yeah, you will still access the endpoint like you used to, but you will need extra work to make it happen.